# How do you call other Anchor functions within another Anchor function?

Tags: anchor-lang

Within a function, how do I call other functions?

```
pub fn process_a(ctx: Context<CreateItemA>) -> Result<()> {
   /// Do something things with item A here...

   /// Now call process_b?
   let returned_value = process_b("test"); <--- What is the proper syntax here?

   /// Do something with returned_value

   Ok(())
}

pub fn process_b(value: String) -> Result<String> {
   /// Do something with value here

   Ok("Some returned value")
}
```

I know I can call these one after another from client side but I was wondering if I can chain it all in one single call if possible on chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look into [Cross-Program Invocations](https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_in_depth/CPIs.html) which is the way to make programs interact with each other on Solana.

If you want a more practical and in-depth explication I can recommend watching [this video](https://youtu.be/AKOWg65QWbQ) by SolAndy.